# Comparable exists clause for Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

In MySQL, we could have

```
SELECT 
    column_1 
FROM 
    table_1
    WHERE 
    EXISTS( SELECT 
                1 
            FROM 
                table_2 
            WHERE 
                column_2 = table_1.column_1);
```

The `EXISTS` clause return true if the subquery result has at least one row. Otherwise, it returns false.

However, it seems that such clause isn't supported in Clickhouse.

What is a Clickhouse comparable query for the above?

Comment: Although Clickhouse *looks* like SQL, it is actually pretty far from a real SQL engine, as your query suggests.  You might want to use the native parser instead.